# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in Powershell Core

Tags: powershell, .net-core, aws-sdk, powershell-core

Im trying to use the AWS .Net SDK in my powershell script. My script works without error in Windows Powershell 5, but whey I try running it in Powershell Core 6, I get the error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
Add-Type -Path (${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} + “\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\net45\AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2.dll”)

$EndPoint = [Amazon.RegionEndpoint]::USWest1

$Client = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient -ArgumentList $EndPoint

$tablename = "foo"

$table = [Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table]::LoadTable($Client, $tablename)
```

I expect the last line to run without error, but in Powershell Core it throws the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, and I am guessing you have found the solution to your problem. If so, please share here so we can conclude this question.

For helping other if in case hit this thread, please check https://github.com/aws/aws-tools-for-powershell and understand how to get PowerShell tools to get it working for .net core.